# CakePHP join issue

Tags: cakephp

This is driving me crazy. This is not throwing any errors but it is also not performing the joins. I'm hoping that this is one where I've spent too long looking at it and the answer is obvious to someone else...

```
        $lines = $this->RevenueLine->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'RevenueLine.is_triggered' => 1,
                    'RevenueLine.date_triggered >=' => $sqldate1,
                    'RevenueLine.date_triggered <=' => $sqldate2,
                ),
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'projects',
                        'alias' => 'Project',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'RevenueLine.project_id = Project.id'
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'clients',
                        'alias' => 'Client',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Project.client_id = Client.id'
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'classifications',
                        'alias' => 'Classification',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Project.classification_id = Classification.id'
                        )
                    )                       
                ),
                'order' => array(
                    'Client.client_number ASC', 
                    'Project.pn_counter ASC'
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: What does it do? does it just return 0 rows?

Comment: It pulls everything from RevenueLine table but nothing from the others. Same result with a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the fields from the joined tables:

```
'fields' => array(
     'JoinTable1.*',
     'JoinTable2.*',
     'JoinTable3.*',
     'JoinTable4.*'
)
```

as a parameter of your find.

Comment: That has resolved the issue, thank you. I *swear* I have run other finds like this one without specifying fields and it automatically fetched all fields from each table (including the joins). :-)

Comment: Thanks Barry! I too was having the same issue! This is not mentioned anywhere in the cookbook... http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables